# php array into javascript array document.write javascript_array

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem with my javascript array. Bellow my code:

```
$namen = array();
    $mainimg = array();
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE id = ".$id.";");

        echo "<div class='normal'>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
        {
            $namen[] = $row['bild']; 
            $mainimg[] = $row['mainimg'];
            $number_array = count($namen);
            ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            <?php
            for($a=1; $a <= count($namen); $a++){
                $php_array = array($a => $row['bild']);
                $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
                echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
                echo "document.write(javascript_array + '<br />');";

                }
            ?>
            </script>
        }
```

Now I get [object][Object] in the browser, but I wanted to printout the elements, the name of the pictures. What can I do?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards, Yanick

Comment: i dont see the point of the js here at all, you could simply use php for it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to print a `Object` as a `string`. What you need to do is to access your properties directly from the object.

```
<script>
<?php $data = array('foo' => 'bar'); ?>
var my_js_var = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

With this script, you can access your values like this:

```
document.write(my_js_var.foo); // writes 'bar'
```

Comment: Perfect!!! :-) It works. No I get ["test1.jpg"] for example. Is there an easy way to get only test1.jpg?

Comment: You could test if `$php_array` has a single value, but this would increase your code and may not be worth it. Unless it will always be a single value, so you don't need to use an array, or even JSON, just pass the value to the JS var, with single quotes, and it will be a string. Glad it helped. If it fits, consider accepcting the answer :)

Comment: I would like to make a image gallery so I have to put the values into an javascript array. :-( I have it now like this:   $php_array = array($a => $row['bild']); .... $a++;   Now I get eg. {"1":"test.jpg"} in the browser. Can I get just test.jpg with document.write. I would like to test it, because afterwoods I need the test.jpg as a source for the picture which changes by clicking on next- or prev-button

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the array and output the fields you want for each item. You're currently printing out the string version of an object in JavaScript, which is always `[object Object]`.